# Built in Emulator WXGA800 7inch (4.1.1) Not selecting correct resources

Tags: android

I am testing on the Android 4.1.1 emulator with the WXGA800 - 7inch version. This has a resolution of 800x1280 with density of 213dpi. I have the following folders

drawable
drawable-h1200dp
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-ldpi

I have the same directory structure for 'layout'

Problem I have is for this 'built in' emulator the drawable-h1200dp resources are not being selected so the images are small. The height is 1280 so this should select the h1200dp should it not or have I got it wrong? If someone could explain

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can set the abstract LCD density when you EDIT or CREATE a new AVD, Android cares more about the pixel density rather than the resolution itself when it has to choose what layout it's supposed to pick among the several resources available.